# Alternatives to inheritance for components with different behaviours?

Tags: c#, inheritance, component

I have been learning a lot of inheritance in C#. But am wondering if there are other ways that can be cleaner for component based setups.

I have objects that are all pretty much the same but they have a unique behaviour tied to them, which i currently just override a virtual method.

So every new component i'm making a new class that inherits the Component base class.

Are there cleaner ways to do this in C# rather than have 15 scripts of a class of each component and their unique behaviour?

Pseudo example of the inheritance i have:

```
Base Class - Component
WaterPump : Component
   //unique behaviour moves water around a system
PowerGenerator : Component
   //unique behaviour creates power units and adds to the system
enter code here
WaterGenerator : Component
   //unique behaviour creates water units and adds to the system

....the list goes on
```

They have other unique behaviours beyond just simple add/create but just wanted to explain the situation. I have a lot of classes for every single type that requires unique behaviour.

It's starting to get a bit silly - but i don't know how to attach a behaviour to a component so i am not creating a new derived component every single time. 
Is there any design setup i can do that can improve this?

Comment: I'm confused by how `PowerGenerator` and `WaterPump` are seen as related. Seem pretty different to me. What do they have in common? What is the justification for giving them a common base class?

Comment: They are both components connected to a system. So they both have base class Component. But they have different behaviours, one generates units to the system (generators), the other moves units around the system (pumps) in this case electricity doesn't require a pump since it propagates instantly in my case. But water moves subject to the pump's information.

Comment: "They are both components connected to a system." Sorry, I am not sure what that even means. In software, pretty much *everything* is a component of something. What is the difference between `Component` and `System.Object`, in your solution?

Comment: What do you mean ? Think of a water system in real life. A tap is a component of the system just as much as the pump, but they have different unique behaviour that effects the system, tap removes the water from the system, the pump moves the water around the system. They are both components in said system. This is the same idea in my code - any entity in the system is naturally a component of the system, but has its own unique behaviour.

Comment: Not trying to be pedantic. I find that these design questions often resolve themselves when I force myself to be very specific, so there is a purpose to this madness. Now. The spigot on my house and the pump in your office are not in the same system, so that does not explain a relationship between *types*, only between certain *objects*. What do the *types* have in common? Does Component offer any common properties or methods? Or do you just need the capability of storing spigots and pumps in a single list, i.e. a List<Component>? Why is that better than using a List<object>, for example?

Comment: Uh both your spigot and pump are part of the same system, that being the water system in your city. I don't see how you think they are different systems ? You're just choosing to pick a small scope of the system vs a grander one. 

Components can be turned on or off, they can be damaged which makes them non functional. All components have this from the base class `Component`. Pumps, taps, etc all have this.

So a tap is a component in the water pipe system, just as much as the pump is a component in the water pipe system.One is at the start of it the other is at the end of it.

Comment: I said "my spigot and *your* pump." I'm on a different continent so I doubt we're in the same water network. The point is that there is an important difference between things being connected (composition) and things being similar (inheritance).  But you've listed some similarities so I think I have my answer, and a much better understanding of the question, so thanks for that.

Comment: Based on the questions from @JohnWu, and the answers provided, I think the best architecture would be if you put the compositional (structural) part of your system, Component, into one class, and make the unique behavior parts, child objects or fields within the Component class (if child objects, within a collection field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is by passing an instance of an object to the constructor of your component class. This instance contains the data and behavior that may vary, whilst the component class contains that which is common.

Your instances can either be classes with a common base class/interface, or delegates, even lambdas.

Comment: But doesn't each unique behaviour then still need to be a derived from some base behaviour ? Does this really get around having lots of derived classes ?

Comment: Yes, you can use composition via fields or method arguments to vary behavior in the same way you use inheritance.

Comment: In fact, inheritance is entirely unnecessary. It is a convenience. Inheritance allows you to share fields and code both, without writing explicit calls to a shared instance.

Comment: Not sure i understand what you mean by compositions via fields. Can you show a pseudo example so i understand?

Comment: If i have a field `Behaviour` and apply say `Generate : Behaviour` 

Well each behaviour might need different arguements in its main 
run method so would i also then be constantly cast checking from component?

Comment: You could call a method on the Component and pass in an object that contains the "context" needed for any of the behavioral objects needed. The context would contain the superset of all possible argument values. It is not especially elegant. An alternative is to write a visitor-type, potentially recursive, graph traversal that applies an action delegate to each Behavior field. Such an action would need to dynamically cast (using "as") or double-dispatch.